# Generate image with caption using Magick.NET

Tags: c#, imagemagick, magick.net

I am trying to generate an image file of a caption for scaling. Using the command prompt I have been able to achieve this goal:

```
convert -background lightblue -fill black -font Arial -size 530x175  caption:"This is a test." caption_long_en.png
```

I am now trying to do the same using Magick.NET

```
class ImageResizer
{
    public Image ResizeImage()
    {
        MagickImage image = new MagickImage();
        image.BackgroundColor = new MagickColor(Color.lightblue);
        .....
    }
```

But am admittedly having some trouble: After initializing my image I don't see options to define the fill, font, size and caption that I wish to use to generate my image.

Could anybody point me in the right direction for how to accomplish the command line above using Magick.NET?

Comment: Define "some trouble" please.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst..sorry should have been more specific.  After initializing my image I don't see options to define the fill, font, size and caption that I wish to use to generate my image.  I was trying to gain some more understanding on how to define those options using Magick.NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The options that are specified before the image is read (`caption:"This is a test"`) need to be specified with the MagickReadSettings class. Below is an example of how you can use that class:

```
using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage())
{
  MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings()
  {
    BackgroundColor = MagickColors.LightBlue, // -background lightblue
    FillColor = MagickColors.Black, // -fill black
    Font = "Arial", // -font Arial 
    Width = 530, // -size 530x
    Height = 175 // -size x175
  };

  image.Read("caption:This is a test.", settings); // caption:"This is a test."
  image.Write("caption_long_en.png"); // caption_long_en.png
}
```

Comment: is there a way to account for right to left language conversion in the caption (i.e. if my string is in Arabic)?